# Dropdown values deselected

Tags: java, select, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I need to select product attributes via three dropdowns, it selects fine, however, sometimes, for me on random basis, prior refreshing or hitting the pricing button, some values got back to first selection, like "None" , which fails the process, is possible to secure or lock selected values within dropdown to ensure it wouldn't be removed?

Following is my simpler code, working on random basis:

```
Select select1 = new Select(config.canContractDurationSelect);
select1.selectByVisibleText(duration);

Select select2 = new Select(config.canDurationSelect);
select2.selectByVisibleText(canDuration);

Select select3 = new Select(config.canBoardSelect);
select3.selectByVisibleText(board);

driver.navigate().refresh();

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(config.goToPricingButton).perform();
```

I tried to put condition to check values prior finishing, but it has the same effect, e.g.:

```
String selectedCanBoard = config.canBoardSelect.getText();

   if (!selectedCanBoard.equals(board)) {

    new Select(config.canBoardSelect).selectByValue(board);
    driver.navigate().refresh();
            }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you refresh the site before clicking the pricing button?

Comment: Because somehow, even if goToPricingButton is identified by id and still visible, selenium (my script) can't find it, refresh had been some kind of desperate workaround, which made it visible again..

Answer (score 0):

My bad, there is loading image appearing every time selection is made and selections made in background had been sometimes cleared out. Waiting after each selection for loading picture to disappear fixed the problem.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(config.loadingImage));
```